# Assign key value pair array to 2 arr objects typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to write this out in a simpler and cleaner way in typescript

```
getMonthNames() {
this.months = [{ name: 'Jan', value: 0 }, { name: 'Feb', value: 1 }, { name: 'Mar', value: 2 }, { name: 'Apr', value: 3 }, { name: 'May', value: 4 }, { name: 'Jun', value: 5 },
{ name: 'Jul', value: 6 }, { name: 'Aug', value: 7 }, { name: 'Sep', value: 8 }, { name: 'Oct', value: 9 }, { name: 'Nov', value: 10 }, { name: 'Dec', value: 11 }];
this.toMonths = [{ name: 'Jan', value: 0 }, { name: 'Feb', value: 1 }, { name: 'Mar', value: 2 }, { name: 'Apr', value: 3 }, { name: 'May', value: 4 }, { name: 'Jun', value: 5 },
{ name: 'Jul', value: 6 }, { name: 'Aug', value: 7 }, { name: 'Sep', value: 8 }, { name: 'Oct', value: 9 }, { name: 'Nov', value: 10 }, { name: 'Dec', value: 11 }];
```

}

Comment: You can start with a random date in Jan, use a date formatting lib to get 3 char month, for loop for 12 iterations, populate the array with value as index+1, name as month name, accumulate in an array. Add one month at the end of each loop.

Comment: Maybe I need to be more clear I was wondering how can I assign that key-value pair  to both objects without repeating it
something like:
 this.month=this.tomonths=[{ name: 'Jan', value: 0 }, { name: 'Feb', value: 1 }, tc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems like you want to deep copy the object array. The simplest way to do this, would be to `stringify` followed by `parsing`, something like [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) method from Lodash.

Here is what you should do, to avoid retyping:

```js
this.months = [
  { name: 'Jan', value: 0 }, { name: 'Feb', value: 1 }, 
  { name: 'Mar', value: 2 }, { name: 'Apr', value: 3 }, 
  { name: 'May', value: 4 }, { name: 'Jun', value: 5 },
  { name: 'Jul', value: 6 }, { name: 'Aug', value: 7 }, 
  { name: 'Sep', value: 8 }, { name: 'Oct', value: 9 }, 
  { name: 'Nov', value: 10}, { name: 'Dec', value: 11}
];


// Deep copying here
this.toMonths = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.months));

// false: because they refer to different objects
console.log(this.months[0] === this.toMonths[0])

// true: because the values within those objects are the same
console.log(this.months[0].value === this.toMonths[0].value)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/qWJarm)

Comment: Thank you, that is precisely what I  was trying to achieve

Comment: Hey @user2533398 , if this answer has helped you solve your problem, please [consider  accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157936).